# Search File Or Class quickly from the solution In VS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

If there are lots of projects in one solution and each of them has lots of .cs file. 
Also, there might be one more classes in one file.

So, what I want to ask is: How can I find a file or a class quickly?

I really don't like use the `ctrl+F` every time.

Is there any plugin like if I click the `CTRL+SHIFT+R` it will open a window of show a class list or a file list and I can input the keyword what I'd like to find.

Then, when I double click the result, the file will be opened for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In VS2010 at least, there is the [Navigate To](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/01/13/searching-and-navigating-code-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx) feature.  It indexes file names, classes, and methods for quick searching.  Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (comma) to bring up the dialog:

[image]

Also, if you don't mind paying (and getting additional features), there is [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/default.asp) and [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), both of which I believe support VS2008/VS2010 and have source navigation features.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out the "Productivity Power Tools" extension for VS2010.
It adds a new menu called "Solution Navigator", which has a search box with autosuggest, that enables searching your solution.

it has lots of other features and I highly recommend it.